# print names of all the files which contain this string

Tags: python

```
import os
List = os.listdir("location of folder")
os.chdir("location of folder")
for file in List:
    obj=open(file,"r")
    while True:
    line=obj.readline()
    line=line.lower()
    matchcount=line.count('automation',0,len(line))
    if(matchcount>0):
        print "File Name ----",obj.name
        print "Text of the Line is ----",line
        continue
```

The loop is iterating only for one file and execution is stopped I wanted it to iterate over all files in a directory

Comment: @ironfist Your edit made an irregular indented but loading program into something that throws an IndentationError on loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of tiny improvements that can be made to your program. I'll rewrite it with comments so that I can keep the answer short.

```
import os
import os.path

def find_grep(d, s): # Wrap this up as a nice function with a docstring.
    "Returns list of files in directory d which have the string s"
    files = os.listdir(d) # Use better names than "List"
    matched_files = []    # List to hold matched file names
    for f in files:       # Loop over files
        full_name = os.path.join(d, f) # Get full name to the file in question
        if os.path.isfile(full_name): # We need to only look through files (skip directories)
            with open(full_name) as fp:# Open the file
                for line in fp:# Loop over lines of file
                    if s in line: # Use substring search rather than .count
                        matched_files.append(f) # Remember the matched file name
                        break # No need to loop through the rest of the file
    return matched_files # Return a list of matched files
```

You can run it like so `find_grep("/etc/", "root")` (will find all top level files in the `/etc` directory that have the string `root` in them).

Answer (score 1):

> os.listdir(path)
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in
>   the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does
>   not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present
>   in the directory.

`listdir` returns files and directories, You should check that the variable `file` is a file or directory.

Use `os.path.isfile`

> os.path.isfile(path)
>
> Return True if path is an existing regular file.
>   This follows symbolic links, so both islink() and isfile() can be true
>   for the same path.

In your Case:

```
import os

location = {your_location}
List = os.listdir(location)
os.chdir(location)
for file in List:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        obj = open(file, "r")
        for line in obj.readlines():
            line = line.lower()
            matchcount = line.count('automation')
            if matchcount > 0:
                print "File Name ----", obj.name
                print "Text of the Line is ----", line
                continue
```