# Finding text files with specific matching numbers or string in the filename

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a file with the column head serial numbers Head serial #

This is a list of serial numbers:

```
Head serial #
UG0013
UG0025
UG0043
UG0053
UG5214
UG5246
UT5324
UT0244
TH7035
TH7106
TH7212
TH7218
TH7362
C499277BT433
D499241BD221
D499227BQ004
B500438BZ921
B500425BZ933
```

I need to find all the text files on a network folder that have these numbers in the filename. Please help!

Here is my code so far which is currently returning ALL .txt files but I only want the files with the above serial numbers in the name Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

""" This is the master file for reading the lifetest lasers """

masterfile_location = 'C:/Users/gallachj/Documents/Lifetest_Master.xlsx'
#df = pd.read_excel(masterfile_location)



from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel(masterfile_location, sheet_name='Sheet1')

#print("Column headings:")
#print(df.columns)
#print(df['Head serial #'])
sns = df['Head serial #']
headtypes = df['Head type']     
colors = df['Wavelength (nm)']
powers = df['Power rating (W)']

import fnmatch
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/gallachj/Documents/')

for file in os.listdir('.'):
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
# if    fnmatch.filter(sns, '*.txt')
(print(file))`
```

Comment: You might be able to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135304/print-names-of-all-the-files-which-contain-this-string).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print names of all the files which contain this string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135304/print-names-of-all-the-files-which-contain-this-string)

Answer (score 0):

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135628/9333067) from *Noufal Ibrahim*, you can try something like this:

```
import os
def find_filenames(d, s): 
    try:
        files = os.listdir(d)
    except PermissionError:  # network drives usually have a lot inaccessible folders 
        return []

    matched_files = []
    for f in files:  # loop over elements in folder
        full_name = os.path.join(d, f) # get full relative name
        if os.path.isdir(full_name): # recursive call
            matched_files += find_filenames(full_name, s)
        elif os.path.isfile(full_name): 
            if any(serial in f for serial in s):  # check the filename
                matched_files.append(os.path.realpath(f)) # Remember the matched file
    return matched_files # Return a list of matched files

find_filenames(r'\\40i2039p-0\d\_Mer_', ['search', 'words'])
```